# Manipulating pointer values inside functions taking pointers as arguments

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have read a lot of questions of stackoverflow, but couldn't find any solutions on how to deal with this problem of allocating and manipulating pointers inside functions: Can anybody please tell me what's wrong with this code? (I want to allocate and assign values to *D through pointerpass and print the same through pointerprint)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float *D;

void pointerpass(float **ptr1)
{
    *ptr1=(float*)malloc(3*sizeof(float));
    *(ptr1+0)=1.33;
    *(ptr1+1)=2.33;
    *(ptr1+2)=3.33;
}

void pointerprint(float **ptr2)
{
    int j=0;
    for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        printf("\n%f\n",*(ptr2+j));
}

int main() 
{
    pointerpass(&D);
    pointerprint(&D);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent the code- i.e. make it readable

Comment: And why are you making life so difficult. You can pass back the result of `malloc`]

Comment: In C, `*ptr1=(float*)malloc(3*sizeof(float));` - the `(float*)` cast is redundant.

Comment: Also, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`.

Comment: Also, don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: @EdHeal Indent'ed' it. I am new to C. Can you please tell me why should we pass the result of malloc?

Comment: @Deduplicator Why doesn't *(a+b) work, but Bluepixy's code in the answer below works?

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845). Most important, a cast says to the compiler: Shut up and do as I say. Bluepixy gave you corrected code, he didn't point out any errors, syntax- or style-points.

Comment: `ptr1 + 1` meant `&ptr1[1]`. but you want `(*ptr1) + 1`

Comment: E.g. `*(*ptr1+1)=2.33;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void pointerpass(float **ptr1){
    *ptr1=(float*)malloc(3*sizeof(float));
    (*ptr1)[0]=1.33;
    (*ptr1)[1]=2.33;
    (*ptr1)[2]=3.33;
}
void pointerprint(float **ptr2){
    int j=0;
    for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        printf("\n%f\n", (*ptr2)[j]);
}
```

Comment: Programming language can be represented exactly.

Comment: @Deduplicator why can't we cast malloc?

Comment: @user3748848 , No problem just redundant it simply **correct** case. But cast it wrong often human error is made​​. Not required even though  do it.

Comment: Well, it is not a code of enough explanation needed exaggerated. ;D

Answer (score 1):

Here we go

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float * pointerpass(){
   float *ret = malloc(3*sizeof(float));
   ret[0] = 1.33f;
   ret[1] = 2.33f;
   ret[2] = 3.33f;
   return ret;
}
void pointerprint(float *array) {
    int j=0;
    for (j=0;j<3;j++) {
        printf("\n%f\n",array[j]);
    }
}

int main() {
   float *x = pointerpass();
   pointerprint(x);
   free(x); // We do not like memory leaks
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Finally understood it!! Thanks a lot.